# Keyboard not being dismissed

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uitextfield, swift4

I realize this is a trivial question with tons of answer on SO. I may just need a pair of fresh eyes as I've triple checked everything and cannot see where I am going wrong with this. I just want to dismiss the keyboard on hitting the return key. I'm setting the delegate properly and implementing the proper methods, so why won't the keyboard dismiss?

Does having a `collectionView` in the `viewController` complicate things? (text field is NOT inside `collectionView`)

```
class SearchController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UITextField!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchBar.delegate = self
    setupUI()

}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

Things I've tried:

- cleaning the project
- restarting xcode
- changing the `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()` to `textField.resignFirstResponder()`
- setting the delegate for the text field inside IB instead of in `viewDidLoad`

What the heck am i missing here!?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in `textFieldShouldReturn(textField:)` does it actually call `searchBar.resignFirstResponder()`?

Comment: no it doesnt seem to be @GuyKogus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement the proper text field delegate method. There is no such delegate method as `textFieldShouldReturn(textField:)`. The proper method is `textFieldShouldReturn(_:)`.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    return false
}
```

The `_` makes a huge difference. You may have copied an old Swift 2 implementation.

It's best to let Xcode perform code completion to ensure you get the correct signature of any method you are implementing or calling.

Comment: geez. thank you. i spent 2 hours overlooking an underscore :D

Answer (score -1):

Use this code

```
view.endEditing(true)
```

Comment: inside the shouldReturn method?